# What is the algorithm of OrientDB partitioning?

Tags: orientdb, partitioning, graph-databases, titan, database-partitioning

I can't find the partitioning algorithm which is supported by OrientDB.
I need a graph database which is supports clever algorithm of partitioning or rebalancing to decrease the number of cutted edges (edge which points on another server). Because I have a lot of reads but few writes.
Also, does Titan database support some clever algorithm?

Comment: Hi Alexandr, I found the [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Partitioned-Graphs.html) and [Titan](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/graph-partitioning.html) docs about partitioning. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Lucas, thank you for your response. I have already read those articles but unfortunately they didn't help. The first article "Partitioned graphs" it wasn't about partitioning. It was a simple tutorial of vertex and edge creation. The second article "Graph Partitioning" was exactly about partitioning but there was only several words about "Explicit Partitioning" so I can't understand the algorithm (how exactly they partition a graph). I wish there were more information about "Explicit Partitioning" but there weren't. Sincerely